How to connect object tap and screen tap together in Meta Spark Studio
Hi I can’t find a way to get both screen tap and object tap working together. I have 2 objects by taping on the screen object 1 changes to object 2 and vice versa. I want to do the same thing but this time tapping on a button using object tap. Is this possible?
I have connected screen tap to a counter, the counter is then connected to 2 Equals Exactly and then to my objects
I have created a button using plane which is connected to object tap
now I’m not sure how to connect object tap to my 2 objects
 This is what I have so far:
